# How to read a connectionstring in .net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, web-config, connection-string

How do I read a value from the web.config file for a connectionstring in the 4.5 .net framework?

I'm using system.configuration which I have a reference to and a using statement, but the only thing coming up after that to use is `.ConfigurationSettings.Appsettings`.

No connectionstringsettings.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
using System.Configuration;

string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StringName"].ConnectionString;
```

**Edit (Adding in a reference to `System.Configuration`:**

Right click on your project -> Add Reference -> Select the `.NET` Tab -> Select System.Configuration -> OK

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx

Comment: i tried that, but it says that 'the name configuarationmanager does not exist in the current context'

Comment: Did you include the System.Configuration namespace?

Comment: You may also have to add a reference to System.Configuration in your project. Right click on your project -> Add Reference -> System.Configuration

Comment: yes... I have a "using System.Configuration;" statement and have a reference to the system.configuration dll

Comment: i tried recompiling and am getting an error saying "The name 'ConfigurationManager' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @sagesky36 try restarting Visual Studio after you add the reference and namespace

Comment: The reference was in my client, but not in my dal class. I was looking at the referenced dlls from my client app. As soon as i added it to my dal class, it was fine.. what an idiot!

Comment: @sagesky36 glad you got it working. If this answer helped you please upvote it and mark it as the answer.